# How to reduce app size without remove '-ObjC' flag with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have 1 iOS Application, this App requires 3 libraries

Library A has a "libA.a", Objective-c class files in Library A requires "libA.a" file.
Library B has some pictures, Objective-c class files in Library B requires those pictures.
Library C does not have any ".a" or any pictures, just Objective-c class files and a lot of junk files

If I remove '-ObjC' flag in my Application, Library A and B won't work.
If I keep '-ObjC' flag, everything is good, but the app size is huge.
Because that flag will Put all objects include junk files in library C in to final binary.

So my question is, how to set '-ObjC' flag on special library (here is A and B, not C) when working with Cocoapods to reduce final app size.

---